# opendaylight: yangtools how to support "feature" declared as an "if-feature" statement in YANG file?

Tags: opendaylight, ietf-netmod-yang

I am using opendaylight and compiling a yang file which has statements like

```
  if-feature "ipv4"
```

When I compile the yang file and run a valid looking json file through it, I get

```
  Schema node with name l3 wasn't found under (urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-access-control-list?revision=2018-01-16)matches.
```

As I understand it, the feature has to be "enabled on the server" before the generated json file can be parsed. How do I enable the feature on the server?
Do I need to enable a flag in the mvn plugin that generates java source code? If so what flag? Thanks.